# java - opencsv class works perfect individually but doesn't write CSVs when called by another class

Tags: java, csv, parsing, servlets, opencsv

I'm using html form to take input of a file and uploading it using `doPost()` method of `HTTPservlet`. [This part is done in package one] Now function from class `Main.java`  to parse the uploaded file is called in this doPost method. This function resides in the other package. [Moving to the other package-> ] Here the class `Main.java` calls `Integrated.java` which has all the instances of class and functions needed to be called in order to parse the file that was uploaded. (I have separate classes for extracting data, chunking, sorting and generating  csv out of the data parsed)

After I parse the file, I put values in variables which are initialized in the last file `CSVgenerator.java`. Values to these variables are added before in the class `SortAndOutput.java`. To test that I'm getting the right values in my class, I print the variables right before I call the functions `writingDatabase()` and `writingTraining()`. These two functions save the values of the variables in CSV files.
I'm using OpenCSV for writing the files. Using apache Tika for extraction of data and lingpipe to parse.

**THE BIG PROBLEM**:
I (intentionally) write main func in CSVgenerator.java and test it. Both the files are written properly. The missing value columns are left blank. PERFECT! (If i have any of the CSV open separately, it raises an exception like it should)

But when i comment out the main func and run the whole project together on server, the CSVs are not written. Even if the files are opened separately(outside eclipse), it doesn't give an error.
I have tested the whole integrated Java code by putting a main method in `Main.java` and it runs perfectly. The problem occurs when servlet is run/I run project on server.

I don't know if other files will be helpful or not, I'm posting the hierarchy and CSVgenerator class
[Workspace Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Pjx.png)
**CSVGenerator.java**

```js
package com.fypv1.parser;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.opencsv.*;
public class CSVgenerator {

 public static String CGPAinitial="-"; 
 public static String universityNameOut="-";
 public static String emailIDOut="-";
 public static String phoneNoOut="-";
 public static String phpKnow="NO";
 public static String databaseKnow="NO";
 public static String jsKnow="NO";
 public static String bootStrapKnow="NO";
 public static String aspKnow="NO";
 public static String htmlKnow="NO";
 public static String cssKnow="NO";
 public static String jqueryKnow="NO";
 public static String jspKnow="NO";
 public static String reactjsKnow="NO";
 public static String ajaxKnow="NO";
 public static String oopKnow="NO";
 public static String javaKnow="NO";
 public static String androidKnow="NO";
 private int idNumber;
 Writer wr;
 Scanner scanner;
 
 /*
  * public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  
 new CSVgenerator(); 
 }
 */
 //DEFAULT CLASS CONSTRUCTOR
 CSVgenerator() throws IOException
 {
 String trainingCSV = "TrainingData.csv";
 String databaseCSV = "databaseInfo.csv";
 String idNumberFile = "idnum.txt";
  
    try {
  scanner = new Scanner(new File(idNumberFile));
  SortAndOutput.applicantIDnumber=scanner.nextInt();
  idNumber=SortAndOutput.applicantIDnumber;
   
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  System.out.println("IDnumberFileUnavailable");
 }     
 
 try {
  wr = new FileWriter(idNumberFile);
  int newIDNumber=idNumber+1;
  wr.write(newIDNumber+"");
  wr.close();
 } catch (IOException e1) {
  //   
  e1.printStackTrace();
 }    
 //System.out.println( String.valueOf(idNumber)+"+"+universityNameOut+"+"+CGPAinitial+"+"+emailIDOut+"+"+ phoneNoOut+"+"+CGPAinitial+"+"+phpKnow+"+"+ databaseKnow+"+"+ jsKnow+"+"+ bootStrapKnow+"+"+ aspKnow+"+"+ htmlKnow+"+"+ cssKnow+"+"+ jqueryKnow+"+"+ jspKnow+"+"+ reactjsKnow+"+"+ ajaxKnow+"+"+  "?");
  writingDatabase(databaseCSV);
  writingTraining(trainingCSV);

 }//CONSTRUCTOR ENDS
 
 
 
 void writingDatabase(String databaseCSV) throws IOException {
  CSVWriter dbWriter;
  
  String [] record1={String.valueOf(idNumber),universityNameOut,CGPAinitial,emailIDOut, phoneNoOut };
  dbWriter= new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(databaseCSV, true));
  dbWriter.writeNext(record1);
     dbWriter.close();
  }

 void writingTraining(String trainingCSV) throws IOException {
  CSVWriter trainingWriter;  
  
  String [] record={String.valueOf(idNumber),CGPAinitial,phpKnow, databaseKnow, jsKnow, bootStrapKnow, aspKnow, htmlKnow, cssKnow, jqueryKnow, jspKnow, reactjsKnow, ajaxKnow, "?"};
  trainingWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(trainingCSV, true));
  trainingWriter.writeNext(record); 
  trainingWriter.close(); 
  }
 
 }
```

**Integrated.java**

**ResumeUploadService.java (the servlet)**

```js
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {
                        Part file = request.getPart("file");
                        resumeFileName = Paths.get(file.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
                        file.write(path + resumeFileName);
                        printOnClient(response, "Upload Successful!");
                     }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        printOnClient(response, "Upload Failed!");
                        }

            new Main(path,resumeFileName);

    }
```

Please let me know if more code is needed to debug this.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @RC. The project is huge :/ how do i do that?

Comment: Your files are written relative to the execution classpath. Why don't you give absolute paths?

Comment: Sorry; this code is illegible. Please a) stick to Java naming conventions and b) put your code through a full and correct format before posting. Your IDE should be able to do that for you with a single click.

Comment: @cricket_007 Please explain what you mean. For future, I would like to adhere to what you just asked me to do

Comment: @BoristheSpider How do i do it my IDE?

Comment: I found out what the issue is. It was updating files both times. When it ran on server, it created files in eclipse folder and when i ran as java application, it updated files in project folder. 
So i corrected it by putting files in an absolute path and giving the whole path in the variable. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> It was updating files both times. When it ran on server, it created files in eclipse folder and when i ran as java application, it updated files in project folder

Your files are written in the application folder unless otherwise specified. This is the *relative path* to the running application.

Just because you tested the application in Eclipse doesn't mean that the server deployment would write to the same folder.

Ideally, you can specify a configuration parameter to your Servlet for an *absolute path* where files are to be stored